# Jquery div hide on load selector value not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 kind of `<div>`'s. Here is these structure:

```
<div id="acf-field" class="field field_type-relationship field_key-field_59f736725fe5d" data-field_name="levesek" data-field_key="field_59f736725fe5d" data-field_type="relationship" style="display: block;">


<!-- Hidden Blank default value -->
<input type="hidden" name="fields[field_59f736725fe5d]" value="">


<!-- Left List -->
<div class="relationship_left">
    <table class="widefat">
        <thead>
                            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input class="relationship_search" placeholder="Search..." type="text" id="relationship_fields[field_59f736725fe5d]">
                </th>
            </tr>
                                        </thead>
    </table>
    <ul class="bl relationship_list">
        <li></li><li class="load-more">
            <div class="acf-loading"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- /Left List -->

<!-- Right List -->
<div class="relationship_right">
    <ul class="bl relationship_list ui-sortable" style="height: 192px;">
            </ul>
</div>
<!-- / Right List -->
```

This is an empty div for me. (because `<ul class="bl relationship_list ui-sortable">` doesn't have `li` child) I have a `field2` and `field3` id as well.

I would like to show that div which has the li and hide those which doesn't contains anything (it could be 3 empty (show all) or only one (hide others) with value)

So I made this jQuery but not working:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery( "#acf-field" ).show();
jQuery( "#acf-field2" ).show();
jQuery( "#acf-field3" ).show();
if (jQuery( "#acf-field" ).find( ".ui-sortable" ).children().eq(0)) {
    jQuery( "#acf-field" ).show();
    jQuery( "#acf-field2" ).hide();
    jQuery( "#acf-field3" ).hide();
}
if (jQuery( "#acf-field2" ).find( ".ui-sortable" ).children().eq(0)) {
    jQuery( "#acf-field2" ).show();
    jQuery( "#acf-field" ).hide();
    jQuery( "#acf-field3" ).hide();
}
if (jQuery( "#acf-field3" ).find( ".ui-sortable" ).children().eq(0)) {
    jQuery( "#acf-field3" ).show();
    jQuery( "#acf-field2" ).hide();
    jQuery( "#acf-field" ).hide();
}
```

Comment: Instead of `eq(0)` use `length` because as they are, all your `if` conditions will be true.

Comment: @Titus you are right `.lenght`seems okay but now the first is true and it stops

Comment: @Titus and doesn't true in my case because it doesn't have any li

Comment: Instead of `children()` try to use `find("li")`.

Answer (score 0):

Are the fields - acf-field, acf-field2 and acf-field3, mutually exclusive? If not then the "if conditions" need to be rewritten with a pairing of else block.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the content of the `ul` is an empty string. If yes, hide it.

Example code for `#acf-field`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery( "#acf-field" ).show();
  if (jQuery( "#acf-field" ).find( ".ui-sortable" ).html()=="") {
      jQuery( "#acf-field" ).hide();
  }
});
```